# Access complete response size in postman test?

Tags: api, testing, postman, postman-testcase

Is it possible to access the complete response size in postman with response body and headers ?

I am able to use the below method to get the size of the response body only

```
pm.response.responseSize
```

it will return the size in bytes.

My test case in postman to get the response size looks like this.

```
pm.test("verify the response size of body", function() {
   pm.expect(pm.response.responseSize).to.be.equal(1024);
  
} );
```

Thank you in advance , if it is possible to get the size of complete response size from postman , since my API gateway does not support size of the response to be greater than 10MB and I am returning the encoded attachments in response, so I need to verify that the size of response does not  cross the upperbound.

Comment: Please refrain from adding solutions to questions (which you added in your edit, and I've now rolled back). Feel free to post a proper answer with your solution, but... it doesn't go in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
console.log(pm.request.size())
console.log(pm.response.size())
```

this gives you the computed size of request and response

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your mentioned function is giving the size of the request. 
But in my test case i wanted to check the size of the complete response.

I have edited the question since the heading of the question was wrong. Thank you for your  input

Comment: Your solution already works what's the issue then ?

Comment: Use response.size()

Comment: response.size() --> gives me the json for the body , header and total , I can get the total from the json

Thank you so much for your solution , i will add the solution in the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
let responseSize=pm.response.size();
pm.test("Verify total response size",()=>{
    pm.expect(Number(responseSize.total)).to.be.below(1800);
    pm.expect(Number(responseSize.body)).to.be.below(1024);
    pm.expect(Number(responseSize.header)).to.be.below(800);
    }
);
```

Response contains body and header.For total response size use .total,
for body size use .body & for header use .header